# DirectX Performance in Windows8 App vs Desktop

Tags: performance, windows-8, directx

Is there a performance difference between DirectX in a Win8 Desktop App versus DirectX in a Win8 (Store) App?
I am not interested in XAML.

Afaik the store apps use a `run - suspend - end` cycle so I suppose there could be a small performance loss through abstraction. Am I right with this assumption?
Or is there no noticeable difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some additional startup and shutdown delay due to the animations that occur automatically (fractions of a second).  Once you're in your render loop though it should be equivalent performance - there's no extra abstraction for native app code.